# Can't Add Users SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and I've (admin) user which is have all privileges, Also i was created an (admin assistant) user but this user cannot create an access to other users he just can create a group :
for Example:

> People and Groups ==> New ==> New Group
>
> ```
>  People and Groups ==> New ==> Add Users (this option only appears to Admin) 
>  How can i have it on the other user???
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a permission level of full control so that they can add/remove users or groups. For more details on permissions you can visit this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx).